# Foolproof RequiredIf Error Message Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foolproof-validation

I have my model with:

```
[RequiredIfTrue("OtherField", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} cannot be blank")]
[Display(Name = "The Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I set the `ErrorMessage` then I was expecting that, in validation, the error message was `"The field The Name cannot be blank"`, but I'm getting "The The Name field is required.".

Did I miss something? Why I'm getting the default message?

**PS**: I don't know if makes any difference but I'm using server side validation (ModelState).

**UPDATE**

In the same model I have `Required` (Native from .Net) being used, and `Required` works well. But **all** `RequiredIf` doesn't.

Comment: Code looks correct. Are you sure you have the latest bits deployed? Also, you might consider wrapping the field name in single quotes or square brackets for readability: `"The field '{0}' cannot be blank"`

Comment: I'm update all foolproof dlls but still don't working.

Comment: Any resolution to this?  I'm having the same issue.  It behaves the same for me on client-side validation so it's not just server-side.

Comment: Looks like I've narrowed it down to my custom EditorFor fields.  "Out of the box" EditorFor fields show the expected ErrorMessage but for my custom EditorTemplates, it uses the default MVC ErrorMessage and ignores the FoolProof defined ErrorMessage.

Answer (score 0):

If `Nullable` is enabled in the the `.csproj` file, then the property will be required by default unless it’s declared as `string?`.

Validation for that property could be returning two errors; the default .NET error is probably first in the list, so that’s the one that gets displayed.